# How to get the last line of a SQL table with some conditions

Tags: php, sql, bash

I'm having some problem with the following bit of code in my BASH script. I want to get data from `my_table`. I want to get the `LAST(timestamp)` from the last line which has the `1` value in the `sensor_id` column. So I looked over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp) for some help.

```
  dbq="SELECT LAST(timestamp) FROM table_list.my_table WHERE sensor_id=1"
    mysql -uUSER -p'PASSWORD' >>myvar << EOF
    $dbq
    EOF

    echo $myvar
```

Once I get this information, I want to echo it out with bash.

The error I recieve is:

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(timestamp) FROM table_list.my_table WHERE sensor_id=1' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no LAST() function in mysql.

Can your try select as below :

```
dbq="SELECT timestamp FROM 
        table_list.my_table WHERE sensor_id=1 
            ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"
```